# How can I get the value of a specific winrm property?

Tags: powershell, winrm

How do I go about getting only one of the values returned from the PS command below?

```
PS C:\Users\vagrant> winrm get winrm/config/winrs
Winrs
    AllowRemoteShellAccess = true
    IdleTimeout = 7200000
    MaxConcurrentUsers = 10
    MaxShellRunTime = 2147483647
    MaxProcessesPerShell = 25
    MaxMemoryPerShellMB = 300
    MaxShellsPerUser = 30
```

Specifically, I'm trying to to get only the value of `MaxMemoryPerShellMB`. Ultimately I need to compare that value to another value so I can be sure to set it correctly if needed.

Comment: `(Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB).Value`

Comment: That worked. Question: What is WSMan and how does it compare to winrm? IE, for winrm the path is winrm/config/winrs, but wsman is WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB. What's this mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use WS-Management provider to get or set WS-Management configuration options:

```
(Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB).Value
```

> What is WSMan and how does it compare to winrm?

You can say, that them both refer mostly to the same thing:

> Windows Remote Management (WinRM) is the Microsoft implementation of WS-Management Protocol, a standard Simple Object Access Protocol (SOAP)-based, firewall-friendly protocol that allows hardware and operating systems, from different vendors, to interoperate. [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384426.aspx)

All the options of `winrm get winrm/config` available under `WSMan:\localhost\` PowerShell path. Some of them can use different naming, like `Shell` instead of `winrs` (Window Remote Shell), but in most cases names match. You can explore available configuration options by standard PowerShell commands, like `dir WSMan:\localhost\`.

Comment: As of PS 3.0 you can setup different plugins too, which can be seen with `winrm enumerate winrm/config/plugin -format:pretty` or in PS with `dir Microsoft.WSMan.Management\WSMan::localhost\Plugin`

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the `winrm` output to a [hashtable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692803.aspx):

```psh
$winrs = & winrm get winrm/config/winrs |
         Select-Object -Skip 1 |
         Out-String |
         ConvertFrom-StringData
```

and access the desired value like this:

```psh
$winrs['MaxMemoryPerShellMB']
```

or like this:

```psh
$winrs.MaxMemoryPerShellMB
```